# How to insert new row in table throught Filemaker pro 11?

Tags: filemaker

I have created table product and also created layout with some edit field that bind to product table columns.Using this i can easily navigate the row data but my problem is I want to insert new row into the table,How can i do this??

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your question isn't very clear, but if you're simply trying to add a record to the table, choose Records>New Record (Cmd-N/Ctrl-N key equivalent by default).